# How could I bar_plot this data.frame?

Tags: r, dplyr

```
vertejumi_ceturksnos <- data.frame(
  Vertejumi = c("0", "1", "2", "3"),
  Pirmais   = c(Pirmaiss),
  Otrais    = c(Otraiss),
  Tresais   = c(Tresaiss),
  Ceturtais = c(Pirmaiss)
)
```

Produced df
[image]

I want to make a bar plot out of these values, so x axis <- are compared with values("Pirmais","Otrais","Tresais","Ceturtais") <- corresponding to quarters of the year,
and y axis <- have bars reaching to the amount in the table, and the amounts are corresponding to the 0:3 values in the first column

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, if your data format is identical as the image and i understood the question, should work.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
    
   


vertejumi_ceturksnos %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -Vertejumi) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = factor(name, 
                          levels = c("Primais", 
                                     "Otrais", 
                                     "Tresais", 
                                     "Ceturtais")),
               y = value, 
               fill = Vertejumi))+
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
    labs(x = "x label", y = "y label")
```

Answer (score 1):

Reshaping the data using `melt` looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape)
vertejumi_ceturksnos %>%
  melt() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = Vertejumi)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Tried this aswell, and works perfectly aswell, thank you!